# Is it possible to Run automated tests from test plans in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests

By looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops) for running automated tests from test plans it states:

> A test plan containing your automated tests, which you have associated with automated test methods using Visual Studio 2017, or Visual Studio 2015 or earlier.

Has anyone had success running it in VS2019 or do I have to downgrade my VS2019 to VS2017 in order to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone had success running it in VS2019 or do I have to downgrade my VS2019 to VS2017 in order to make it work?

No, you don't need to downgrade the Visual Studio. I have been creating and running automated tests in Visual Studio 2019 before. And it could work as expected.

Here are the steps:

1.In Visual Studi0 2019 , you need to [associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops) in Test Explore.

2.In Azure Devops, you can follow the steps in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops) to create the same build and release. It also applies in  Visual Studio 2019.

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

I could reproduce this error:

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to select the **Test Run** in `Release Pipeline -> VSTest task`.

[image]

**Update2:**

You need to set up test assemblies in the build pipeline.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I've tried this multiple times. Whenever I choose "Test Assemblies" or "Test Plan" in the VsTest task then I get the error: "Validating stage: The selected stage does not have the right version or settings of the Visual Studio Test task to run tests.".
The only option I can choose without getting this error is "Test Run" but under the documentation it says that it should not be chosen for running tests in a continuous integration / continuous deployment pipeline.

Comment: Hi @Chronospear. In continuous deployment pipeline, you need to select Test RUN. Then the auto test will work fine. Please refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#set-up-your-environment  The Set up steps indicates that the test run is required in Release Pipeline。

Comment: Here is the doc about the feature of test run: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#q-how-does-selecting-test-run-in-the-visual-studio-test-task-version-2-work

Comment: Thanks for the help. I choose test run but it can't find my test assemblies even though I have all of the necessary DLL's. (Related [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11607) ). As of my understanding I still need to specify where the test assemblies are located, correct? If that is the case then how do I do that in Test Run, because it doesn't have that option as Test Assemblies has.

Comment: Hi @Chronospear. You need to create a build a pipeline to build and generate test assemblies . Then you could use the artifacts to run the test run in release pipeline. Please refer to my update

Comment: I followed your steps and got it somewhat working. It located the test files but now it complains that 'dotnet' is not installed (even though it is). Similar issue with same error message: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2337